# Excel VBA to update cell values within table with variable number of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of data which needs certain values to be changed based upon the value in column A.  The data resides in a column headed Analysis\xx where xx is a variable value from 1 to 60.  The number of columns varies per row, so that row 4 may go up to Analysis\4 whereas row 5 might go up to Analysis\30.  Every value appearing in the Analysis\xx field needs to be updated, where a certain value exists in column A.

I have code to update values based upon a single fixed column position but I'm struggling to work out how to iterate through each row to update a variable number of columns.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

I've attached a sample of the data below which shows a good selection of the variation, with the columns that don't need amending hidden.  Row 26 actually goes all the way to column NB.

[image: Data Sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table has a name you can use the follwoing code to loop through each row off column A and in this case just print the value of a column in the same row.

```
Sub Tester()

Dim rg As Range
Dim rgA As Range
Dim sngCell As Range

    Set rg = Range("Your TableName")
    Set rgA = rg.Columns(1)
    For Each sngCell In rgA.Rows
        Debug.Print sngCell.Offset(, 3).Value2
    Next

End Sub
```

Does that code go in the right direction?

EDIT: Assuming you use a listobject, this code might help you

```
Sub ChangeTable()

Const ACCT_NO = "ABCD1234"
Const HEADING = "Analysis*"
Const NEW_VAL = "80321"

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim hdrCount As Long

    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Your Name here")
    hdrCount = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Columns.Count

    For x = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
        With tbl.ListRows(x)
            If .Range(1, 1).Value2 = ACCT_NO Then
                For i = 2 To hdrCount
                    If tbl.HeaderRowRange(i).Value2 Like HEADING Then
                        .Range(1, i).Value = NEW_VAL
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I think so, but I only need to look for columns where the value in the header row is called Analysis\xx.  The number of analysis columns changes in each file and it could be anything from 4 to 60+.  There are also at least another 50 columns of data which I don't want to change.

Comment: Hit enter by mistake. The query needs to be use the logic 'for each cell where accountnumber  = ABCD1234 and column heading = analysis\1 to x, change value at intersect to 80321'

Comment: Question: Do you use Listobjects in your sheets?

Comment: that was a great help, thank you.  The only point left is to only update cells which already contain a value.  The code above updates all cells with the relevant column/row value irrespective of the existing cell contents.

Answer (score 0):

Hallo have you tried to use something like this for which TEST1 is the Varibale you like to replace and Test2 is the Variable you like to chnage it to ? This code does it for the entire Worksheet.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Cells.Replace What:="TEST1", Replacement:="Test2", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: In the sample above, every value in columns Analysis\xx for AccountNumber ABCD1234 need to be changed to 80321, irrespective of what the field currently contains.  The new Analysis\xx value will be fixed by the AccountNumber.  I only need to change the value where the column heading is Analysis\xx.  In the data above, it goes up to Analysis\57 (366 columns wide including the other relevant data which isn't changed). There is usually about 200 rows in each file and maybe 20-30 of these are affected.